# Are diagonal border lines possible in HTML / CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Just realized I have yet to see this.

But can not believe it isn't possible.

I'm looking to draw a triangle in pure CSS/HTML.  An equilateral if possible.

**Clarification:**

I don't wish to use an image to achieve this.

You would need to be able to put content inside the div.

Comment: Do you mean like this: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: @Schleis +1 internetz to you. I've been developing for a while, and never come across that site. Thanks!

Comment: For whatever reason that border is actually pushing the content outside of my div...Never had this problem before.

Comment: I think this is useless if you want to have content inside the shapes -> http://jsfiddle.net/9eYJr/1/

Comment: [Approach for newer browsers that doesn't rely on border.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193526/css-3-html-cut-edge/15193681#15193681) May give you some ideas.

Answer (score 6):

### One Solution

Diagonals are not easy. One solution is to overlay pseudo-elements to create the border, assuming you are dealing with solid background colors. Then you have to position the content to make it look nice. You could even do some [text wrapping](http://www.csstextwrap.com/examples.php).

[**Here is a basic example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6rfRV/3/) using this code:

**CSS & HTML Respectively**

```css
.triangleBorder {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 173.2px; /* for equalateral = Width * (sq.root 3) / 2 */
    }
    
    .triangleBorder:before {
        content: '';
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -2;
        border: 100px solid transparent;
        border-top-width: 0;
        border-bottom: 173.2px solid black;
    }
    
    .triangleBorder:after {
        content: '';
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 1px;
        top: 1px;
        z-index: -1;
        border: 99px solid transparent;
        border-top-width: 0;
        border-bottom: 171.5px solid white;
    }
    
    .triangleBorder span {
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       text-align: center;
       top: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="triangleBorder">
    <span>Content<span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few different approaches for creating the equilateral triangle shape using CSS. Creation of diagonals is still not any easier  but now the shape can at-least have a transparent background even when the body has a gradient (or) an image as its background.

**Option 1:** Using Pseudo-elements and Skew Transforms

In this method we use a couple of pseudo-elements and skew them in opposite directions (inward) to create the diagonal lines whereas the line at the bottom is produced using a `border-bottom` on the parent. We can also produce trapezoids using this approach.

**Cons:** This approach would not work if the `body` background and `shape` background are different and the `body` background is not a solid color.

```css
.triangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape1 {
  height: 174px;
}
.shape2 {
  height: 101px;
}
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  bottom: 0px;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
.triangle:before {
  left: 0px;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}
.triangle.shape1:before {
  transform: skew(-30deg);
}
.triangle.shape2:before {
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
.triangle:after {
  right: 0px;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}
.triangle.shape1:after {
  transform: skew(30deg);
}
.triangle.shape2:after {
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
.triangle span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
}

/* Just for demo */

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #400, #100);
}
.trapezoid {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
.trapezoid:before,
.trapezoid:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  bottom: -1px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
.trapezoid:before {
  left: 0px;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
.trapezoid:after {
  right: 0px;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
.trapezoid span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class='triangle shape1'>
  <span>content</span>
</div>
<div class='triangle shape2'>
  <span>content</span>
</div>

<br/>


<!-- Just something extra to illustrate -->

<div class='trapezoid'>
  <span>content</span>
</div>

<br/>
```

---

Here is a **variation of Option 1** which would work when the background of the `body` and that of the shape are different and the `body` background **is a solid color**.

```css
.triangle{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;  
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  color: red;
  background: beige;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape1{
  height: 174px;
}
.shape2{
  height: 101px;
}
.triangle:before, .triangle:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 101%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: red;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
.triangle:before{
  left: -200px;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
.triangle.shape1:before{
  transform: skew(-30deg);  
}
.triangle.shape2:before{
  transform: skew(-45deg);  
}
.triangle:after{
  right: -200px;  
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}
.triangle.shape1:after{
  transform: skew(30deg);
}
.triangle.shape2:after{
  transform: skew(45deg);
}

.triangle span{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
}

/* Just for demo */

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  background: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='triangle shape1'>
  <span>content</span>
</div>
<div class='triangle shape2'>
  <span>content</span>
</div>
```

Here is another **variation of Option 1** which supports gradient background for both inside and outside the triangle shape.

```css
.triangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape1 {
  height: 174px;
}
.shape2 {
  height: 101px;
}
.triangle:before,
.triangle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 99%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
.triangle:before {
  left: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #003333, #773333);
}
.triangle.shape1:before {
  border-top: 4px solid white;
  transform: skewY(-60deg);
}
.triangle.shape2:before {
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
}
.triangle:after {
  right: 0px;
  top: 0%;
  border-top: 3px solid white;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #773333, #FF3333);
}
.triangle.shape1:after {
  border-top: 4px solid white;
  transform: skewY(60deg);
}
.triangle.shape2:after {
  transform: skewY(45deg);
}
.triangle span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
}


/* Just for demo */

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #400, #100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='triangle shape1'>
  <span>content</span>
</div>
<div class='triangle shape2'>
  <span>content</span>
</div>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Triangles with different angles can be easily created by modifying the `skew` angle and the height of the parent `div`. But, as we are using `skew` the borders tend to become thinner as the skew angle approaches 90deg (or -90deg) but that shouldn't be too big a problem because with such high angles you can barely have fit any text inside.

---

**Option 2:** Using Linear Gradients

In this method, we use a couple of angled `linear-gradient` backgrounds (each of which are 50% width of the container) and slant them in opposite directions to produce the diagonal lines.

```css
.triangle {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 174px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49.5%, white 49.5%, white 50.5%, transparent 50.5%), linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 49.5%, white 49.5%, white 50.5%, transparent 50.5%);
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  background-position: 1px 0px, 99px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.triangle span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
}
/* Just for demo*/

body {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #400, #100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='triangle'>
  <span>content</span>
</div>
```

**Cons:** Angled gradients are known for producing jagged lines.

> **Note:** Irrespective of which approach is chosen, you would still have to do text wrapping to make the text stay inside the shape.