# CSS negative triangle with inverted rounded corner

Tags: css, css-shapes, rounded-corners

Hello is it possible create a triangle with inverted rounded corner in the center of a rectangle, like in many landing page. Something like the below image:

[image]

I found something similar here but without inverted rounded corner
[CSS Inverted Triangle image overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374069/css-inverted-triangle-image-overlay)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve this effect by using two pseudo-elements. We need to position one of the pseudo-elements with respect to the left of the container while other is positioned with respect to right of the container. Then by adding a `transform: skew()` on them in opposite directions and assigning a border-radius to the required sides we can get the required output.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: blue;
  background-clip: content-box;
  /* make sure blue background doesn't appear behind triangle */
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  width: calc(50% + 10px);
  /* don't change */
  height: 50px;
  /* must be equal to padding-top */
  background: blue;
}
div:before {
  left: 0;
  transform: skew(45deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
}
div:after {
  right: 0;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'>This is a shape.</div>
```

Comment: wow thank u! It's possible add text in that div? i try here http://jsfiddle.net/nhqKb/284/ the triangle is great, but the text doesnt shown

Comment: @Harry,  Damn...fast as lightning XD

Comment: sorry i paste the wrong link was another arrow without rounded corner, i edit that 60 second later, u was faster :)

Comment: Hehehe but not as fast as Harry :p

Comment: @JoTaRo: Yes, it can be. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Warning: The triangle is not responsive, if u try to resize the window, the dimension of triangle will change (small window big triangle, big windows very little triangle)

Comment: @JoTaRo: Did you try checking the updated snippet? I have corrected that also already.